# How can i erase/ hide label names in Bio.phylo.draw?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, phylogeny

ive got problem with label names, at pic below i will show you what im mean. 
[e.g cacatua_moluccensis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fYLH.png)

Im using Phylo.draw() function to draw a phylogenetic tree and everything is fine, but one thing is unaesthetic for me, label lines didnt show out of axes at fig field but i dont know why label names did (look at cacatua_moluccensis at pic). Here is code i used:

```
from Bio import Phylo
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax=plt.gca()
tree = Phylo.read("simple1.dnd", "newick")
tree.rooted = True
Phylo.draw(tree, show_confidence=True, axes=ax)
```

I was able to change some things in axes, so i think change displaying of label names its possible.

Comment: What do you want the label names to be? Just want the underscores removed?

Comment: When i am using zoom option in matplot, label names are out of "axes frame" on figure field, I want them invisible on that field. You can notice that tree branches are only in plot frame, but label names change their position overlaping on scale for example.

Comment: This could be a good question for the (in beta) bioinformatics stack exchange: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics